# ARR reverse proxy to Azure Website inside Azure Cloud Service

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, azure, arr

I am trying to rewrite www.contoso.com/blog/ to a wordpress Azure Website (contosoblog.azurewebsites.net). I have completely configured all inbound and outbound rules, and have tested them locally on a development machine and can confirm it works -- e.g. setup www.contoso.com to point to 127.0.0.1 in hosts, hit up www.contoso.com/blog/ and can confirm it loads the wordpress site.

I have followed instructions around the net to install WebFarm Framework + ARR inside an Azure Cloud Service using startup tasks, and remoting to the instance, I can see that WFF and ARR are properly installed. Configuring the site with the same rewrite rules as I have applied to my dev environment, I get a 404 error when I hit www.contoso.com/blog/. I figure the only way I get 404 is if the rewrite didn't occur, so I hit up failed request tracing and looking through the logs, I see that the rewrite rules indeed get hit and URLs are being rewritten, but somewhere in the middle of the log there is an ARR_WEBFARM_NOT_ROUTED error and the URLs are subsequently rewritten back to the original request.

I have searched around everywhere and the ARR_WEBFARM_NOT_ROUTED seems to only generate 1-2 pages of Google results with no helpful information. I have a hunch that it has something to do with how Cloud Services are configured, so I fired up a new Azure Virtual Machine, configure an IIS role and setup WebFarm+ARR. On that server, everything works fine.

Can someone point me to the right direction on how I can fix my problem, or if it is even possible at all?

Comment: Did this get solved? If so can you share your solution?